# How to convert an environment variable declared inside a "yaml" file to something inside the ".env" file?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, .env, nats-streaming-server

I have an environment variable file that is declared like following inside a `deployment.yaml` file:

```
          env:
            - name: NATS_CLIENT_ID
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
```

I am just wondering to know if I want to use an `.env` file instead of the `deployment.yaml` file, how can I declare the above port within the `.env`?

Comment: Where would this `.env` file be?  I suspect it isn't possible, since a `.env` file would normally contain only static values but this YAML block gives the environment variable a different dynamic value for each pod.

Comment: @DavidMaze: Yes I think I should manually define different variables for each pad within the `.env` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can create a configmap that contains your `.env` and use your configmap to inject the environment variables.

An example here: https://humanitec.com/blog/handling-environment-variables-with-kubernetes